# custom link with params inside in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create link for method edit which has to have link like that:
/presentation/:id/edit.

```
 <% @presentations.each do |p| %> 
     <a >  <%= p.id %>
     <a href="<%= presentation_path(p) %>" target="_blank" class="action"> Show </a> 
     <%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", '/presentation/:id/edit', {target: "preview" } %>
    </a>
   <% end %>
```

my link above is giving me error:
RuntimeError in PresentationController#edit

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: define it in your routes.rb

Comment: Can you show the code from your controller that initializes @presentations? It looks as though it contains at least one null. Also, you probably want to change that last link to 'edit_presentation_path(p)' or something very similar, rather than '/presentation/:id/edit' which will put a literal ':id' in the url.

Comment: what is this `<a >  <%= p.id %>` before another <a> tag for??

Comment: my controllers:  def list
    @presentations = current_user.presentations
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to terminal and execute

```
$ rake routes
```

and you will find text like this: `edit_presentation`. So replase your `'/presentation/:id/edit'` to `edit_presentation_path`
It will help